# Run application at startup and hide it automatically

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager

I have a basic autostart script that runs apps on startup.
It's as simple as:

```
#!/bin/bash

nm-applet &
ulauncher &

lxappearance &
qt5ct &
```

While `nm-applet` and `ulauncher` start without showing anything, `lxappearance` and `qt5ct` show a window on startup and I have to close it at every boot.

Any idea how to start these apps in the background without showing a window? I am using the qtile tiling window manager.

Comment: my tilling window manager is qtile

Comment: Aren't these GUI programs that require a window? Can they even run without a window? Do you close or minimize the windows?